# JAVA array matching locations

Tags: java, arrays, matching, element

I have a little difficulty with my code. I am trying to match two positions of a scanner with the locations of an array. it works but the problem is that the code is printing the numbers twice. How can i solve this problem?
I also need the print stay visible if the two elements are the same. I already tried to find the same question but i could not find it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class memory {
  int[] memoryGeheugen = {1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 4};
  String sterretjes = "*";
  boolean dubbel = false;
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public void run() {
  System.out.println("voer de cijfers in positie 1");
  int raden1 = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("voer de cijfer in positie 2");
  int raden2 = scan.nextInt();
  for (int i = 0; i < memoryGeheugen.length; i++) {
    if (memoryGeheugen[i] != memoryGeheugen[raden1]){
      System.out.print(sterretjes);
    }
    else if(memoryGeheugen[i] == memoryGeheugen[raden1]&&memoryGeheugen[i]==memoryGeheugen[raden2]) {
      System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden1]);
      System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden2]);
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new memory().run();
}
```

output:

```
voer de cijfers in positie 1:
1
voer de cijfer in positie 2:
4

*33**33*****
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the program ?

Comment: i am trying to make a game called memory.  u have to guess all the pairs to win the game. and if u not guessed the pair the numbers turn back hidden. so far i am trying to do this step by step, but only succeeded partially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement:

```
if(memoryGeheugen[i] == memoryGeheugen[raden1]&&memoryGeheugen[i]==memoryGeheugen[raden2])
```

basically says memoryGeheugen[raden1] and memoryGeheugen[raden2] are equal to one another.

So, if you're printing like so:

```
System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden1]);
System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden2]);
```

Then you'll have duplicated values printed because your logical condition determines them as equal.

Therefore, comment out the second or first line because printing both lines is unnecessary if memoryGeheugen[raden1] = memoryGeheugen[raden2]:

```
System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden1]);
//System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden2]);
```

And, your likely to get non-duplicated values.

Comment: tnx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code it prints double because of the

```
System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden1]); //raden1 = 1 memoryGeheugen[1] = 3
System.out.print(memoryGeheugen[raden2]); //raden1 = 4 memoryGeheugen[4] = 3
```

This will print

> *33**33****

Use `System.out::println` if you want them in separate lines

```
if (memoryGeheugen[i] != memoryGeheugen[raden1]){
  System.out.println(sterretjes);
}
else if(memoryGeheugen[i] == memoryGeheugen[raden1]&&memoryGeheugen[i]==memoryGeheugen[raden2]) {
  System.out.println(memoryGeheugen[raden1]);
  System.out.println(memoryGeheugen[raden2]);
}
```

This will print them in separate lines

> *
> 3
> 3
> *
> *
> *

Comment: if i change it nothing happen because of the != prints '*' above it. the purpose of the code is that it prints it double, but not twice in a row right next to each otherl(33***). or is that not what u meant? tnx for the reply

Comment: @user7418776 I think I updated the answer according to your needs.

Comment: tnx for the time and answer, i will try to find another way to do this. because i need it lined up at the exact location of the scanner input.